# "Add connections" or "Create connections"?

Tags: expression-choice

I am building an interface for making connections between items.

When viewing a particular item, the user has the possibility of connecting it to other existing items, by selecting them from a list.

Which expression is better? Is "add connection" even correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For regular usage, either expression would work. However, *create connection* implies that the connection has not yet been made, while *add connection* implies that the connection exists and that it is simply being added to a list.

Given what little I know of your situation, I'd say that *create connection* is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I think that both options are fine.  You might even consider using *connect* as a verb :  *connect item* or *connect items*, for instance.

I think that *add connection* has the advantage of being shorter.  (Of course, even shorter would be, *add link*, *create link*, or something similar.)

*Create connection* has the advantage (or disadvantage) of implying that connections are *not* generic, latent items that just need to be activated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work, in my case.